# Conditional style in cognos graph

Tags: report, cognos

Is it possible to apply a conditional style depending on another column?

I have a chart that shows a machine's productivity over time.

[image: Graph]

Every few weeks, there is a maintenance operation on these machines and I have the dates stored in another table. I would like to change de color of the 'Production brut' square when a maintenance operation has been done.

I tried conditionnal styles with 'Date de Production' = 'Date de maintenance' but nothing happens. 
I already managed to do a simple condition (Change color when 'Production brut' > Production standard')

Comment: Some questions: 1. Have you done a join to merge the two tables? 2. Can you provide the actual Advanced Conditional Styles expression?

Comment: 1. The two tables have been joined
2. In the end I found a way to this , not very elegant though. Because the dates are grouped by weeks (Which was maybe the problem) , I did a count query and the conditional style is if the count is > 0

Comment: You said you created "count query". Is this a separate query or did you misspeak and mean data item?